# htmlspecialchars $_POST and empty string, PHP 5.4 and ISO-8859-1

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

after updating to PHP 5.4, I can't have working a script I'm using, and I found the problem being htmlspecialchars (I get empty string with € symbol and accented characters).

I tried with a simple form in an html page:

```
    <form action="special.php" method="post">
    field1: <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

and in special.php:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[field1]); ?>
```

setting different charsets in the header (ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, UTF-8), specifying different parameters for the function (flags, character-set), and also trying htmlentities, but couldn't find a solution.

Any idea if I'm missing something or something should be changed in server configuration?

Thanks a lot,
Igor

Comment: What are you typing into the form field that you expect to see on the second page?

Comment: Probably not related, but `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[field1]); ?>` should be `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['field1']); ?>`

Comment: @vascowhite: it's related :). The thing about the missing ' has been changed between PHP4 and 5, in PHP4 his example code would work without any notice. In PHP5 it throws an error/notice, related to the used PHP configuration.

Comment: @JustAPirate I didn't mention any behaviour :)

Comment: Narg...i meant the missing ' you mentioned, need more coffee :(

Comment: No change adding ' . Actually it works fine without if no htmlspecialchars is used.

Comment: If can help, I have to specify cp866 as character-set to make it work.